# Error "JSON parse unexpected non-whitespace character " in php

Tags: php, json, jsonencoder, contenttype

I have a big DB data to display. If i do this with just PHP/SQL, it result too big and it take too long for showing data.

So i prefere to display all data with **AJAX**. But, when i create the PHP page for encode the data to JSON, and then add the *header('Content-type: application/json');*, i get this error:

*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 388 of the JSON data*

At the moment when i edit the script, and delete/comment the line *'header('Content-type: application/json');'*, the results are correctly displayed.

So, first, i create a function that take all data that i need:

**Orders.php**

```
 public function getOrders(){

        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $fluent = new \Envms\FluentPDO\Query( $db->getConn());
        $query = $fluent
        ->from('en_orders o')
        ->innerJoin('en_carrier AS c on c.id_carrier = o.id_carrier')
        ->innerJoin('en_address AS a on a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery')
        ->innerJoin('en_order_carrier AS oc on oc.id_order = o.id_order')
        ->select('o.date, o.en_reference, o.id_order, o.id_cart, o.ps_reference, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.address1,
        a.address2, a.postcode, a.city, a.telephone, a.mobile, c.name, o.module, oc.colli, oc.weight, o.total_shipping,
        o.total_paid_tax_inclu, o.id_order');

        return $query ;
    }
```

Then, in **view_ordini_ajax.php** there is the processing of data. I choose to stock all in a multidimensional array (and i believe that this create the problem):

```
    $ordini = new Orders();

$results = [];

header('Content-type: application/json');

foreach($ordini->getOrders() as $row){

    $results = array(
        'id_order' => $row['id_order'],
        'id_cart' => $row['id_cart'],
        'date' => $row['date'],
        'en_reference' => $row['en_reference'],
        'ps_reference' => $row['ps_reference'],
        'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
        'address1' => $row['address1'],
        'address2' => $row['address2'],
        'postcode' => $row['postcode'],
        'city' => $row['city'],
        'telephone' => $row['telephone'],
        'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'module' => $row['module'],
        'colli' => $row['colli'],
        'weight' => $row['weight'],
        'total_shipping' => $row['total_shipping']
    );
    echo json_encode($results);
};
```

Normally, the JSON is like that:

```
{"id_order":TEST,"id_cart":TEST,"date":"2019-06-10 18:24:26","en_reference":"TEST","ps_reference":"TEST","firstname":"TEST","lastname":"TEST","address1":"TEST","address2":"TEST","postcode":"TEST","city":"TEST","telephone":"TEST","mobile":"","name":"Corriere Standard","module":"TEST","colli":1,"weight":"13","total_shipping":"10.000000"}
```

How can i get the entire json keeping the content-type ? And why i get this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`json_encode` outputs a JSON text and you have it in a loop.

So while you are saying you are sending a JSON text, you're actually sending a file with **multiple** JSON texts all jammed up against each other. The first one parses, then it hits the `{` from the second one after the parser thinks it should be finished … so it errors.

- Create an array before the `for` loop (you are doing this already, but you overwrite it)
- Push `$results` into that array (`$results[] = array(etc` — note the `[]`!).
- `echo json_encode($results);` **after** the loop instead of `inside the loop.

---

You also need to make sure your client is expecting to receive an array of data from the JSON.